# How to Set Custom Widths in Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Is it possible to set custom widths in bootstrap 5? The docs only mention setting the width relative to the parent(25%, 50%, 75%, or 100% of the parent's width) or relative to the viewport (vw-100 etc.).
I'm trying to achieve something like this:
`<div class="w-25rem"> <div>` which would set the width to 25rem.
Is this possible with Bootstrap or must I use inline styling or create a new class with the styles I want?

Comment: I guess BS5 does not have that but I ll wait for others to comment

Answer (score -1):

You can use inline CSS in Bootstrap 5, but you'll have to use !important like this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).